# jVectormap onRegionOver callback

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm not a jQuery person, but in implementing jVectormap I've included an onRegionOver function when the map initially loads. However, it seems that it fires only once, ie the content of the #content div displays correctly once, but persists when moving the cursor over other states. What am I missing?  TIA.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.jvectormap').vectorMap({
  map: 'us_en',
  values: associateData,
  scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
  hoverOpacity: 0.7,
  hoverColor: false,
  onLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
  el.html('<strong>'+el.html()+'</strong><br />'+associateData[code]);
  },
  onRegionOver: function(e, code){
    $("#content").replaceWith(contentData[code]);
  },
  markers: [
          {latLng: [43.30, -75.61], name: 'Dans Automotive, Taberg NY', r: 3, fill: 'yellow'},
          {latLng: [41.16, -95.93], name: 'Yecks Auto Repair, Bellevue NE', r:3, fill: 'yellow'},
          {latLng: [41.36, -81.85], name: 'Parkway Express, Berea OH', r:3, fill: 'yellow'},
          {latLng: [41.31, -81.83], name: 'Strongsville Express, Strongsville OH', r:3, fill: 'yellow'},
      {latLng: [41.34, -81.53], name: 'Nordonia Tire &amp; Service, Northfield OH', r:3, fill: 'yellow'}
        ],
        onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, index){
          console.log('label-show', label, index);
        },
        onMarkerOver: function(event, index){
          console.log('marker-over', index);
        },
        onMarkerOut: function(event, index){
          console.log('marker-out', index);
        },
        onMarkerClick: function(event, index){
      var url = "http://www.google.com";
      $(location).attr('href',url);
        }
    });
  })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this string

```
$("#content").replaceWith(contentData[code]);
```

you replace `#content` element with something else. After that `#content` element does not exist on the page anymore and could not be changed then. You probably want to use `html` method instead:

```
$("#content").html(contentData[code]);
```